# Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to get my Rails app working on my VPS. I've deployed my project, created the database and migrated it. But when I visit the page I get a message:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

My nginx error log show me this:

```
App 12380 stdout:
App 12380 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
[ 2014-11-03 11:44:12.9549 12050/7fd1a0bb8700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/wisemonkeys/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
  Error ID: 20eb13ee
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-dyuK5v.html
  Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
<pre>
*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
</pre>

[ 2014-11-03 11:44:12.9630 12050/7fd19e833700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 20eb13ee. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

I've tried to read https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems but it's just too technical for me at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem. I'm not using RVM `/home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby:` In my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I had

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.2/ruby;
```

But I needed to have:

```
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```